# Unable to add multiple objects to firestore at the same time using Batch

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write multiple objects to a firestore collection, but Firestore is only taking the last object even using batch.
Essentially, you have the option to add 2 fields (Adding multiple students) at the same time (I provide an input box and an option to add more input boxes), I store this in an object array and then use a for loop to store it in Firestore, but everytime I add 2 or more students only one object is taken into the firestore collection.

This is my current code

```
  for (let i = 0; i < studentsCount; i++) {
const batch = firestore.batch()
console.log(engineCompanies2.names[i])
const engineCompanyRef = db.collection('engineCompanies').doc(engineID)
batch.set(engineCompanyRef,       
  {
    [engineCompanyID]: {
      studentName: engineCompanies2.names[i],
      studentAssigned: 'null',
      studentDilligence: 'No',
      studentReport: 'No',
      studentStatus:'Yes',
      studentPriority: '0',
      studentSignals:0,
      studentID: engineCompanyID,
    },
  },
{ merge: true }
,);

batch.commit().then(function () {
  console.log('Yes')
```

});

Any help with this please and thank you.

Picture of Console, swapped out students for company
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyQBO.png)

Comment: `.doc(engineID)` you are updating the document with same `engineID` (at least it's not visible in the loop). Are you trying to add each item in array as it's own document with `engineCompanyID` or a single document with the array?  Can you share a screenshot from Firestore console of an example doc maybe?

Comment: Your code is not checking for errors on the call to commit.  Please do that and edit the question with the new code and its behavior.

Comment: @Dharmaraj added the picture! Idea is you are creating an entirely new document for example, 2022 Chemistry class, the user is adding multple students at the same time as objects in that collection

Comment: So you want to add multiple maps/object with random ID in a _single document_? I won't recommend using such keys as field name as it might cause issues in indexing later.